# Is there a SQL Function that I can use to return a range of rows for a Primary Key?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `Word` where the primary key is:

```
 [WordId]       VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
```

What I would like to do is to create a select inside a stored procedure that will return all the rows from this table where the first character of `WordId` is between A-E or F-K or some other range based on two characters I pass into the stored procedure.

Can someone give me advice on how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LIKE pattern syntax supports ranges so you can just use

```
 WHERE WordId LIKE '[A-E]%'
```

Or a slightly more dynamic version.

```
DECLARE @Start char(1) = 'A', @End char(1) = 'E';

IF @Start > @End
    RAISERROR('Start must be before or equal to end',16,1);

DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(10) =  '[' + @Start + '-' + @End + ']%';

SELECT Foo
FROM Bar
WHERE WordId LIKE @Pattern
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer.  I would like to put this into a stored proc and pass the lower and upper characters in. So it could be for A-E or F-K etc. Is that still possible with this way of doing it ?

Comment: Yes, just build the pattern by concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT WordId FROM Word WHERE LEFT(WordId,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'E'
```

Comment: This is not sargable.